# Insert data from MySql to QT

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I have connected MySql with QT(Hope so) and i don't know how can i insert data from database to scrollArea. I have looked for this question but didn't find a answer with MySQL. How can i insert data from MySql to scrollArea?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
       db.setHostName("localehost");
       db.setDatabaseName("details");
       db.setUserName("root");
       db.setPassword("pass123");
       bool ok = db.open();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton Cancel = QMessageBox::question(this, "Выход", "Выйти?",
                                                               QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    if (Cancel == QMessageBox::Yes){
        QApplication::quit();
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Button 'Yes' was not clicked";
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_scrollArea_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
   //Data from MySQL must be here
}
```

Comment: I assume you have created a table in your database for whatever data you want to add.

Comment: I have connected with this documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-connecting.html

Comment: Your connection code seems correct. You need to have tables in your database before you can query to add or retrieve data.

Comment: And here is the question: How can i take materials from table in DB and insert it in to my listview?

Comment: mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_details |
+-------------------+
| material          |
| zagotovki         |
+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.24 sec)

mysql> I have tables in my database. But i don't know how to link it with my list

Comment: ***How can i take materials from table in DB and insert it in to my listview*** `QSqlTableModel` or  `QSqlQueryModel`